# VBA grogramatically change query SQL based on user input

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to create a macro that based on a user input (on an excel sheet) will pull data from a query I made in Access. In order for it to pull only the applicable lines (rows) of data it needs to edit the WHERE statement accordingly. I have adapted the following code from a previous question but I am running into issues when I try to replace the SQL.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Const DbLoc As String = "MYfilepath"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim wb1 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, SQL As String, recCount As Long
Set wb1 = Workbooks("mytool.xlsm")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Inputs")
Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets("raw")
Set db = OpenDatabase(DbLoc)
Set userinput = ws1.Range("D6")


SQL = "SELECT Dock_Rec_Problems.Merch_Name, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_Error_Code, Dock_Rec_Problems.DC, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_ID_IP, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_Name, Dock_Rec_Problems.PO_Number, Dock_Rec_Problems.SKU_No, Dock_Rec_Problems.Item_Description, Dock_Rec_Problems.Casepack, Dock_Rec_Problems.Retail, Dock_Rec_Problems.Num_Of_Cases, Dock_Rec_Problems.Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID"
SQL = SQL & "FROM Dock_Rec_Problems;"
SQL = SQL & "WHERE [Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID] =" & userinput

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Not found in database", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No Data"
    GoTo SubExit
End If

ws2.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs

SubExit:
On Error Resume Next
    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Let me know if there is anything I can clear up...thanks!

Original Query SQL

```
SELECT Dock_Rec_Problems.Merch_Name, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_Error_Code, 
Dock_Rec_Problems.DC, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_ID_IP, 
Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_Name, Dock_Rec_Problems.PO_Number, 
Dock_Rec_Problems.SKU_No, Dock_Rec_Problems.Item_Description, 
Dock_Rec_Problems.Casepack, Dock_Rec_Problems.Retail, 
Dock_Rec_Problems.Num_Of_Cases, Dock_Rec_Problems.Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID
FROM Dock_Rec_Problems;
```

Single input SQL

```
SELECT Dock_Rec_Problems.Merch_Name, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_Error_Code, Dock_Rec_Problems.DC, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_ID_IP, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_Name, Dock_Rec_Problems.PO_Number, Dock_Rec_Problems.SKU_No, Dock_Rec_Problems.Item_Description, Dock_Rec_Problems.Casepack, Dock_Rec_Problems.Retail, Dock_Rec_Problems.Num_Of_Cases, Dock_Rec_Problems.Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID
FROM Dock_Rec_Problems
WHERE (((Dock_Rec_Problems.Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID)="D040323000"));
```

Double input SQL

```
SELECT Dock_Rec_Problems.Merch_Name, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_Error_Code, Dock_Rec_Problems.DC, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_ID_IP, Dock_Rec_Problems.Vendor_Name, Dock_Rec_Problems.PO_Number, Dock_Rec_Problems.SKU_No, Dock_Rec_Problems.Item_Description, Dock_Rec_Problems.Casepack, Dock_Rec_Problems.Retail, Dock_Rec_Problems.Num_Of_Cases, Dock_Rec_Problems.Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID
FROM Dock_Rec_Problems
WHERE (((Dock_Rec_Problems.Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID)="D040323000")) OR (((Dock_Rec_Problems.Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID)="D040323012"));
```

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what is the problem? What you are expecting to happen, what is actually happening?

Comment: Yes, so the error I am getting is on the line below my ' Replace the SQL comment. If a user puts D040323000 in a cell and runs my macro it should pull only a single row of data back to the worksheet. If a user inputs D040323000, D040323012 it should return two rows.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `WHERE [column] IN ([comma-separated-values])`? Also, [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: So I added what the SQL looks like when I manually edit it in access but is there a way I can have VBA do this for me based on the actual input from a user? Thanks'

Comment: What's the maximum number of selections you would expect to have? 10?

Comment: 20 would be a rare max...most will be in the 1-5 range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the size of your user input is open-ended, consider using a temp table saved in MS Access with exact structure as your query (can be built with: `SELECT * INTO temp_table FROM myquery`). Then, with each call of the Excel macro:

1. Clean the temp table out with `DELETE`.
2. Iterate through the user input Excel range of cells to append needed rows to table with `INSERT INTO...SELECT`.
3. Create recordset from temp table.

And once again, here is a prime use case for SQL parameterization especially since the query receives user input. A clever, malicious user can potentially clean out your database! But at the very least, code is arguably more maintainable. Because you are using DAO, consider [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx) to bind parameter value to a prepared, saved query and then bind into a recordset.

**SQL** *(save as an MS Access stored action query)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [userparam] TEXT(255);
INSERT INTO Excel_Table (Merch_Name, Vendor_Error_Code, DC, Vendor_ID_IP,
                         Vendor_Name, PO_Number, SKU_No, Item_Description,
                         Casepack, Retail, Num_Of_Cases, Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID)
SELECT d.Merch_Name, d.Vendor_Error_Code, d.DC, d.Vendor_ID_IP, 
       d.Vendor_Name, d.PO_Number, d.SKU_No, d.Item_Description, 
       d.Casepack, d.Retail, d.Num_Of_Cases, d.Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID
FROM Dock_Rec_Problems d
WHERE d.[Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID] = [userparam];
```

**VBA**

```
...
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim cel As Range

Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

' CLEAN OUT TEMP EXCEL TABLE
db.Execute "DELETE FROM Excel_Table"

' ITERATIVELY APPEND TO EXCEL TABLES
For Each cel In userinput.Cells
    qdef!userparam = cel.Value            ' BIND PARAM
    qdef.Execute dbFailOnError            ' EXECUTE ACTION
Next cel

' OPEN RECORDSET TO TABLE
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Excel_Table", dbOpenSnapshot)

If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Recieving problem not found in database", vbInformation+vbOKOnly, "No Data"
    GoTo SubExit
End If

ws2.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
.......
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm having a little trouble saving the action query correctly (super bad with Access). Do you mind walking me through it? When I try to running your SQL a msg box says 'characters found after end of SQL statement.

Comment: Whoops! I accidentally had a premature semicolon. I removed it. Now save the SQL in the query design of MS Access (SQL mode). Be sure to have created *Excel_Table* beforehand.

Comment: Getting application defined error on set qdef = db.querydefs("myquery") line. Other saved queries work but the action query we saved for some reason gets this error... any ideas?

Comment: MS Access does not allow you to save a query with a syntax error. Are you sure the database has a query object named *myquery* fully saved? And I assume `db` is a `DAO.Database`.

Comment: it's actually named "RAG_query" and is correctly saved in the database. Something to note... When I try to run the action query (RAG_query) and enter a userparam manually, it says "the INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name 'Vendor_Error_Code'

Comment: Whoops again! Forgot to add the table alias, `d` in `FROM` and use the actual query name.

Comment: haha this is the strangest thing! I am still trying to run the "RAG_query" manually. After it prompts me to enter a userparam  sometimes It runs correctly but most of the time I still get the same unknown field name error. I will continue to mess with it... please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Ah ha! I had some naming errors that needed alignment. Now the append query pushes to Excel_Table correctly! However, back in VBA world I am still getting application/object defined error on set qdef = db.QueryDefs("RAG_query") line. Any ideas? Thank you for your time and help on this!

Comment: You might not have proper references. But if you can run `.OpenRecordset`, you should be able to run `.QueryDef`. At very top of your Excel VBA module type `Option Explicit` (above and outside of any `sub`). Then click from VBA menu: Debug \ Compile. Check for any errors.

Comment: That worked thank you! Went ahead and marked this answer because of your help. I'm not sure how to implement a Split function in the code to work with multiple inputs though. Is this something you can help with or should I open a new question? Thanks again for the help you have already provided.

Comment: Great. Glad to help. But this answer shows how to run multiple inputs by looping through the `userinput` range (which can hold multiple cells) to iteratively append rows to temp table.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the code you've displayed.  For instance, the *strNewFields*  variable is attempted to be used, before you've set it to anything, here:

```
strNewSQL = strNewSQL & Replace(WHERE_FIELDS, "<INSERT FIELDS>", strNewFields)
```

At this point *strNewFields* is totally blank, but you're trying to do a replace.

I would suggest:

1. Change you *WHERE_FIELDS* Const from

   ```
   Const WHERE_FIELDS As String = "WHERE " _
        & "(((Dock_Rec_Problems.Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID) = <INSERT FIELDS>)); "
   ```

   to

   ```
   Const WHERE_FIELDS As String = "WHERE " _ 
        & " [Dock_Rec_Problems].[Dock_Rec_Problems_DGID] IN (<INSERT FIELDS>); "
   ```

   I find this easier to read then all the nested brackets, it removes the equals sign in preference of the `IN()` statement.
2. Now you want to populate the *strNewFields* variable with whatever inputs they gave you.  Probably using a `Do While Loop` to iterate through the INPUTS.  Each input is added to the *strNewFields* variable something like this.

   ```
   Dim rs as Recordset
   Set RS = currentdb.mydataset  ' You need to modify this line
   rs.Open
   strNewFields = strNewFields & "'" & rs("InputFieldName") & "'"
   rs.MoveNext

   Do While rs.EOF = False
       strNewFields = strNewFields & ",'" & rs("InputFieldName") & "'"
   Loop

   strNewFields = StrNewFields & ")"
   ```
3. Now that you have *strNewFields* populated you can simply run your replace()

   ```
   Replace(WHERE_FIELDS, "<INSERT FIELDS>", strNewFields)
   ```

You need to look at the order in which you are setting variables though, as pointed out above, you've got some order of event issues.

Michael

Comment: OP is also going to have to remove `strNewFields` and the associated replace from `BASIC_FIELDS`

Comment: Working on the second part... currentdb.mydataset. Is this a reference to the Access DB as a whole or a specific table name?

Comment: @Mnathan:  Okay so the currendb.mydataset part is referencing the INPUT table where you users get to say what indices they are looking for, and is just a sample as I don't know what your using.  It probably should look more like :

   set rs = currentdb.OpenRecordset( _italic_yourdatatablename_italic_, dbOpenDynaset).

Sorry, my formatting isn't working well on this question for some reason.

Comment: Ok thanks! so the user inputs are located on a worksheet. so something like set rs = ws1.Range("D6")? I'll also probably need to work in a split OP somewhere for when a delimiter is present but for now I'm just trying to get it to work with a single input.

Comment: @thespecial I changed my code to something I think would be easier to to solve. It also might be easier to tell what I am trying to accomplish. I still have the same end goal but what do you think about that? The error I am getting now is with my line Set rs = db.openrecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot) Thank you for your help!